# Figuring out a IIS app pool crash on production

Tags: c#, iis, crash, dump

UPDATE: I ended up asking, and answering, a different form of this question here: [IIS App Pool crashes about 20 seconds after an OperationCancelledException is logged by middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68761713/iis-app-pool-crashes-about-20-seconds-after-an-operationcancelledexception-is-lo/69274354#69274354)

---

I have an app pool running a .net 472 application that will occasionally crash on our production server. This is the message being logged:

```
A process serving application pool 'MyApi' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The process id was '7472'. The data field contains the error number.
```

Error number: `6D000780`

---

I've run the crash dump through DebugDiag and this is what I'm seeing

```
In w3wp.exe.10496.dmp the assembly instruction at iiscore!W3_CONTEXT_BASE::GetIsLastNotification+62 in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\iiscore.dll from Microsoft Corporation has caused an access violation exception (0xC0000005) when trying to read from memory location 0x2d8ac2e8 on thread 111
```

Thread 111 shows this stacktrace:

```
.NET Call Stack


DomainNeutralILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(IntPtr, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus)+73 
[[InlinedCallFrame] (System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIsLastNotification)] System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIsLastNotification(IntPtr, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus) 
System.Web.HttpRuntime.FinishRequestNotification(System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest, System.Web.HttpContext, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus ByRef)+9b 
System.Web.HttpRuntime.OnRequestNotificationCompletionHelper(System.IAsyncResult)+da 
System.Web.HttpRuntime.OnRequestNotificationCompletion(System.IAsyncResult)+13 
System.Web.HttpAsyncResult.Complete(Boolean, System.Object, System.Exception, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus)+82 
System.Web.HttpApplication+PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception)+562 
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()+49 
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)+16f 
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)+14 
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)+228 
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean)+92 
System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()+169 
[[DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame]] 
[[ContextTransitionFrame]] 
[[DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame]] 


Full Call Stack



ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+a 
KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+e1 
kernel32!WerpReportFaultInternal+581 
kernel32!WerpReportFault+83 
KERNELBASE!UnhandledExceptionFilter+23f 
w3wp!WpUnhandledExceptionFilter+47 
mscoreei!InternalUnhandledExceptionFilter+41 
KERNELBASE!UnhandledExceptionFilter+1a2 
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart$filt$0+3e 
ntdll!_C_specific_handler+96 
ntdll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException+d 
ntdll!RtlDispatchException+197 
ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatch+3a 
iiscore!W3_CONTEXT_BASE::GetIsLastNotification+62 
webengine4!MgdIsLastNotification+19 
DomainNeutralILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(IntPtr, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus)+73 
System.Web.HttpRuntime.FinishRequestNotification(System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest, System.Web.HttpContext, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus ByRef)+9b 
System.Web.HttpRuntime.OnRequestNotificationCompletionHelper(System.IAsyncResult)+da 
System.Web.HttpRuntime.OnRequestNotificationCompletion(System.IAsyncResult)+13 
System.Web.HttpAsyncResult.Complete(Boolean, System.Object, System.Exception, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus)+82 
System.Web.HttpApplication+PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception)+562 
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()+49 
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)+16f 
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)+14 
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)+228 
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean)+92 
System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()+169 
clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+83 
clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+4e 
clr!MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker+102 
clr!QueueUserWorkItemManagedCallback+2a 
clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchInner+40 
clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchMiddle+6c 
clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchOuter+4c 
clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchInCorrectAD+15 
clr!Thread::DoADCallBack+26b 
clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchInner+2e2f 
clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchMiddle+6c 
clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchOuter+4c 
clr!ManagedThreadBase_FullTransitionWithAD+2f 
clr!ManagedPerAppDomainTPCount::DispatchWorkItem+a4 
clr!ThreadpoolMgr::ExecuteWorkRequest+64 
clr!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart+f6 
clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+8b 
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+22 
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+34
```

---

It looks like the error comes from [GetIsLastNotification in IHttpContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/smooth-streaming-client/ihttpcontext-getislastnotification-method), but this seems to be a core part of IIS and not something being called by our asp.net api app? I know I can't find any references to GetIsLastNotification in our entire solution.

I'm not sure where to go from here. I found [this in the MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpapplication.presendrequestheaders?view=netframework-4.7.2), which looks very similar to the error in my dump file, however the application is not using any PreSendRequestHeaders or IHttpModule.

> Do not use PreSendRequestHeaders with managed modules that implement
> IHttpModule. Setting these properties can cause issues with
> asynchronous requests. The combination of Application Requested
> Routing (ARR) and websockets might lead to access violation exceptions
> that can cause w3wp to crash. For example,
> iiscore!W3_CONTEXT_BASE::GetIsLastNotification+68 in iiscore.dll has
> caused an access violation exception (0xC0000005).

Comment: Make sure that Application Pool in IIS, under Advanced Settings has Enable 32 bit Applications set to True.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I advise you to always use `Try Catch` blocks whenever you're using resources and/or manipulating objects.

This way you avoid crashing your system and you can utilize the exceptions by logging the error messages from the thrown exception.

Comment: The problem here is that the IIS app pool is crashing. Normally, an exception in ASP.NET Web API is automatically caught and returned a 500 error to the user. But something is causing the app to crash.